# how to trace in the name of its variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, trace

```
var abc:int=123
trace(abc)
```

//actual output:
123
//my expected output:
abc:123

Although I can type `trace("abc:"+abc)` by hands,but I still want to have a more simple way to trace
I have tried something like

```
function tracee(word){  
trace("word:"+word)  
}
function traceee(word){
var wordd:Srting=word
trace(wordd+word)

}
```

but these functions are not working. 
is it possible to have the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.utils.describeType;

var num:Number = 47;
function customTrace(word:*){
    trace(describeType(this).variable.@name + " : "+word)
}
customTrace(num);
```

[SOURCE](http://www.developria.com/2009/09/as3-reflection-using-describet.html)

Comment: Excuse me, but describeType(this).variable takes you just xml of variables of that this-object.

Comment: yes. certainly; and it do not work if more than one variable available. But it may help him.

Answer (score 0):

No. Variables are passed to functions by link (memory offset) or by value, so you don't have any data about names.

The one thing I can propose - is to use automatic code generation in IDEs. For example, in IntelliJ Idea it is in Settings -> Live Templates, that you can use via ctrl+J in editor.